# Putting Internal Hard Drive in another PC

Tags: hard-drive, software-installation

If I install Ubuntu on my current hard-drive, where this computer and the other computer are 64 bit, would this hard-drive work if I put it in the other computer? I know Microsoft OS doesn't allow that, so I'd like to know if Ubuntu is the same. They're both SATA.

Comment: you should be fine with ubuntu, we do not hve the same restrictions here.

Answer (score 1):

It's a game of chance, and depends on how dissimilar the hardware is. Most of the time it will boot up and simply detect the new hardware as if they were system upgrades, but there are some circumstances where you might have problems.

Graphics Drivers: If you've installed any graphics drivers and the systems don't use the same driver you might get a blank screen. If you are just using the default Ubuntu drivers then you should be fine. I'm referring more to packages you install like fglrx-updates etc.

Networking: You'll have a different network interface, and so it may require you to reconfigure it by hand. [I've never done it but, this may help? http://www.ubuntugeek.com/ubuntu-networking-configuration-using-command-line.html ]